# Showing rightView for UITextField only if empty and not selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm showing a UIButton for the rightView property of a UITextField. I only want to show this button if the text is empty and the user is not editing.

I'm setting the `rightViewMode` property to `UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing` which hides the rightView if I'm editing but I also want the right view to hide if there is text in the text field even if it's not selected. I'm not sure how to setup this behavior.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this? I need a similar thing. Want to show right view button only if the text is not empty regardless of the editing state.